# Sorting List with IComparer returns wrong result

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to sort a list but it does not sort the list right.

```
internal class GraphUtils{
    internal static List<Edge_t> kruskal2(List<Edge_t> e)
    {
       e.Sort(new KruskalComparer());
       printEdgeArray(e,e.Count);
       // Do stuff
    }
    static void printEdgeArray(List<Edge_t> e, int cnt)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(e[i].weight).Append(",");
        }
        ConsoleLog.Log(sb.ToString());
    }
}

internal class KruskalComparer : IComparer<Edge_t>
{
    public int Compare(Edge_t a, Edge_t b)
    {
        if (a.weight+TerrConstants.Eps > b.weight) return -1;
        if (a.weight < b.weight+TerrConstants.Eps) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
} 

class Edge_t
{
    internal Vertex_t V1;
    internal Vertex_t V2;
    internal float weight;
}
```

When `kruskal2` is called, The sorted array is printed on console. But the result is wrong. It's not sorted by weight of `Edge_t`.

> 75.01,78.01,76.51,75.51,75.51,75.01,75.01,75.01,74.51,73.01,71.01,71.01,71.01,71.01,71.01,72.51,71.01,71.01,71.01,71.51,71.51,71.01,79.01,63.01,63.01,59.01,47.01,59.51,47.01,59.01,42.01,47.01,42.01,47.01,47.01,47.01,47.01,47.01,40.01,40.51,40.51,39.51,40.01,39.01,39.01,24.51,38.51,38.51,38.01,37.51,24.51,24.51,24.51,24.51,24.51,24.51,24.51,24.51,40.51,39.01,2.01,2.01,

I'm using Unity3d and the platform is mono 2.5.6.

Why is the result not sorted?

**EDIT:**
TerrConstants.Eps is 1e-6f and it is added to the numbers to make some equality margin. so if the difference is less than `TerrConstants.Eps*2` the two weights are considered as equals.

Comment: Why do you add TerrConstants.Eps to the weights? I mean, when you print your edge array, you only show the weights, but to order them you add that TerrConstants.Eps. That doesn't make sense to me. Try removoing TerrConstant.Eps and see if that way it sorts it ok

Comment: TerrConstant.Eps is 1e-6. It's a margin for equality and has no impact considering the range of numbers.

Comment: I removed the TerrConstant.Eps and the results are now sorted right. I've put TerrConstants.Eps on the wrong side of comparison.

Comment: That was what i thought :) Glad you solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably something wrong with your eps constant.
The following compare function should work.

```
if (Math.Abs(b.weight - a.weight) <= eps)
     return 0;
return b.weight.CompareTo(a.weight);
```

Comment: Unity also has a bool Mathf.Approximately (float a, float b);